# Testing controller specs for PUT without permitting ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, strong-parameters

I have a controller that RESTfully updates a model. The action looks as follows:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  params['skill_list'] = params['skill_list'].join(',') if params['skill_list'].present?
  @user.update!(user_params)
  render nothing: true
end

def user_params
  params.permit(:id, :summary, :skill_list)
end
```

And my spec looks as follows:

```
it "should return 200 if param is for user put is summary" do
  ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
  put :update, id: @bob.id, summary: 'yadayada', skill_list: ['a','b']
  assert_response 200
end
```

Now the flow is the following

1. We need to put the `id` in the `put` spec in order to tell it which `id` to use when updating.
2. Controller finds it and updates the `summary` and `skill_list` fields.
3. However, it also OVERRIDES `id`.
4. If I don't permit `id`, the test fails with `ActionController::UnpermittedParams`
5. If I do permit it, the actual `id` gets replaces (we use `friendly_id` gem so that's unwanted - the numeric ID will get replaced by the slug, rendering the user unusable.

For now we forbade `id` and put the spec on pending - but what is the best practice in these cases?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why did you added this for: `ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise`?

Comment: if you will remove this line, you can also remove the `id` from the permitted params, and everything will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Patient: it hurts when I update my ID column!*
>
> *Doctor: well then stop doing that.*

Remove "id" from the list of permitted parameters. It doesn't belong there.

Updating the model with:

```
@user.update!(user_params)
```

updates the ID column because `user_params` contains an `id` key. Stop doing that:

```
@user.update!(user_params.except("id"))
```